# Execution of code with fork() and operators

Tags: process, fork, parent-child, child-process

could someone please explain this line of code to me and exactly how the parent and child processes will be created?

```
main() {
    if (fork () && fork () )
        printf ("yes");
}
```

And this code as well, where we use the OR operator:

```
main() {
    if (fork () || fork () )
        printf ("yes");
}
```

Thank you!